# 'The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.' and not sure where I'm wrong

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, textview, android-linearlayout

This is my code excerpt for the Numbers Activity: 
Note: 'words' is an 'ArrayList' of type String with elemts ranging from 'One-Ten' with 'size=9'.

```
// Find the root view of the Numbers activity
   LinearLayout rootViewNumbers = findViewById(R.id.root_numbers_LL);

// creating a text view to assign the words to it
   TextView wordView = new TextView(this);

for(int i = 0; i <= words.size(); i++) {

            // setting the text to text view by using the 'i' for index position iterator
            wordView.setText(words.get(i));

            // setting the text view to the root view
            rootViewNumbers.addView(wordView);
        }
```

When I run the app I'm getting the error as

> 'The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first.'

My understanding is that we have declared a text view and now we are iterating through loop to add elements of 'words' ArrayList and adding the text view to the root view. Please help me where am I going wrong!!

Comment: If I declare the TextView inside the for loop the error doesn't appear. So how does this affect?
Also, if we declare the TextView inside the for loop, doesn't that mean we're declaring the TextView object with same name again and again?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the TextView inside the for loop, you will be adding a new view instance to rootViewNumbers each iteration, whilst your code tries to add the same view instance to the parent which throws the exception.

You may edit your code to be:

```
 TextView wordView;

 for(int i = 0; i <= words.size(); i++) {

        wordView = new TextView(this)

        // setting the text to text view by using the 'i' for index position iterator
        wordView.setText(words.get(i));

        // setting the text view to the root view
        rootViewNumbers.addView(wordView);
    }
```